# Investment Bank VWAP Execution ranking

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, quantitative, order-execution, vwap, active-investing

Is there a ranking of Investment Banks institutional VWAP execution algorithms anywhere (who beats the benchmark price most consistently and by how much)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean non-VWAP algos ? A VWAP algo is supposed to track the benchmark, not beat it, I wouldn't expect much differences in their implementations.